# Changing button position makes it move drastically

Tags: unity, c#

I have a button prefab that I'm instantiating like so:

```
GameObject button = Instantiate(Resources.Load("UI/Canvas/Button"), ReferenceToCanvasPanelRectTransform.transform) as GameObject;
```

This part works fine and the button is centered in the panel.

I would like to move the button a little bit though and lets say that the position of the button right now is (0, 0, 0).

If I get the button's RectTransform and attempt to move it like so:

```
RectTransform btn = button.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

btn.position = new Vector2(-20, 20);
```

it makes the button's position move to (-1051.05, 1149.5, -5679).

Why does it move so drastically and why does the Z position even change?

Comment: Did you mean to change its AnchoredPosition relative to its RectTransform parent? Just setting `transform.position` sets its worldspace position, which might be very different than the UI canvas's coordinate system.

Answer (score 3):

`btn.position` sets the absolute position in the world space coordinates, not canvas space. To move it on canvas, relative to anchor, use `btn.anchoredPosition`.

Also, `CanvasScaler` has an effect on how different world coordinates are from canvas coordinates.

Your `CanvasPanel` might be set not as `ScreenOverlay` but as rendered in world space and might even be not centered in the world (`CanvasPanel.transform.position != Vector3.zero`). That's why when you change the absolute position of `btn` it shows very different numbers.

If you want to change `transform.position` relative to current position, use `transform.Translate(x, y, z)` method. It moves the object by x, y, z coordinates from current position.

But for UI elements, stick with `rectTransform.anchoredPosition`. It makes your life so much easier...